# mysql querying in batches

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have over 1 million rows in a table that I have to query through and send emails to users based on that query in a cron job. I have the code like:

```
$start = 0;
$limit = 1000;
while ( true) {
    $query_results = db_result("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $start, $limit");

    if (count($query_result) == 0) {
        break;
    }

    foreach ( $query_result as $result) {
        $email = $result ['email'];

        send_email($email);
    }

    $start += $limit;
}
```

is there a better more efficient way to query through millions of rows in batches? and if the script crashes to avoid sending duplicate emails to people? If the script crashes and gets re-run again, it will send emails to the remaining people without me having to do a db lookup in the code above to check if each person got an email?

The email gets sent every day. It might get sent to some of same people every day depending on whether each person fulfilled certain requirements or not.

Comment: I'm tempted to speciously downvote this question... I think my email address is one of millions already targeted by routines like this, and I have no desire for routines that send email to be more efficient.

Comment: that's why I'm making sure I don't send a duplicate!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store some state in your DB.

You need a table with columns for the batch (mailing) id and for the id of the email in the main table.

Then you `INSERT` a line into that table for each email sent, and you can replace your `SELECT` with:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM email_sent WHERE batch=?) LIMIT ?
```

Alternatively, you can add a column that states whether the email has been sent (or when it was sent). Then you first add all emails for this batch to the table:

```
INSERT INTO batch_email (batch_id, email_id) SELECT ?,email.id FROM email WHERE ...
```

And then you pick the emails to send to from there:

```
SELECT * FROM table JOIN batch_email ON table.id=batch_email.id WHERE NOT sent LIMIT ?
```

and finally, you set `sent` once the e-mail has been sent:

```
UPDATE batch_email SET sent=true WHERE id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do without storing in mysql, if you fetch all data in memory. say your id is indexed so you get all ids value and keep that in array and with your php code you execute

like this

```
  select * from table A where id >1000 limit 1000
```

then at the end of this loop increase the value of 1000 to 2000 and like so untll you reach to the end. with this approach u dont need to update database after each pass